# How to sum a column if a particular column is a weekday and another column contains specific names of a person

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to find total amount spent by each person using the table given beside it, provided excludes Sundays & Saturdays with the help of formulas.

PS: I tried adding another column with `=IF(WEEKDAY(C3,2)<6,F3,0)` in column `G` to find if it is a weekday and then return the amount only on weekday.

Then I used `=SUMIF(D3:$D$31,"Doug",$G$3:$G$31)` in `I7` (Similar formula in `I7:P7`)  to find the total sum for each person.

But I want to know if it is possible to do it without creating any additional columns (i.e. a combined formula in `I7:P7` to find the total amount spent by each person on weekdays.)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `SUMPRODUCT` formula for this.

Put this in I7 and copy across.

```
=SUMPRODUCT($F$3:$F$31,--($D$3:$D$31=I$6),--(WEEKDAY($C$3:$C$31,2)<6))
```